# Added javascript in pdf forms not working after setting format flattening to true

Tags: c#, itext

I have added custom javascript to pdf form fields to perform some conditional formatting.
The script works fine when the form is in editable mode.
When we changed the format flattening to true, the script that i added to the pdf form fields not working.

Method to add script using itextsharp

```
private void AddTextBoxEvent(string fieldName, PdfStamper stamper, string script)
    {
        var item = stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldItem(fieldName);
        if (item != null)
        {
            var dict = item.GetWidget(0);
            if (dict != null)
            {
                var aaDict = dict.GetAsDict(PdfName.AA);
                var action = PdfAction.JavaScript(script, stamper.Writer);
                if (aaDict == null) aaDict = new PdfDictionary();
                aaDict.Put(PdfName.F, action);
                dict.Put(PdfName.AA, aaDict);
            }
        }
    }
```

Example Script we added

```js
if(event.value == 0) event.value = '';
var v = Number(event.value);
if (v>0 && v<100) {event.target.fillColor = color.red;}
else if (v<0) {event.target.fillColor = color.red;}
else if (v>100) {event.target.fillColor = color.red;}
else if (v=100) {event.target.fillColor = color.white;}
if (event.value=='') event.target.fillColor = color.transparent;
```

After setting format flattening to true script not working

```
stamp.FormFlattening = true;
```

Anyone please help to find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us some code and [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Welcome to stack overflow, as well. :)

Comment: Your question sounds very strange. Form flattening means that you **take away all interactivity.** This includes JavaScript. Hence it is **very normal** that the JavaScript stops working after form flattening. Form flattening **removes the JavaScript** and therefore the JavaScript not longer works: it's no longer there. How could it work? Your question sounds as: "I've made scrambled eggs, and now my eggs are broken."